# Exception while showing a downloaded image in windows store apps

Tags: io, stream, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-async

Hi I am downloading an image from the following code

```
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, imageUri);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var fs = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            writer.WriteBytes(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
            await writer.StoreAsync();
            writer.DetachStream();
            await fs.FlushAsync();
            fs.Dispose();
```

But when I try it to open immediately after running downloading code.. with the help of the following code and trying to set as a source to image control

```
            var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(imageName);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            imageControl.SetSource(stream);
```

It throws the following exception

**Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

and Inner Exception is:

**null**

Please let me know that at which point I am doing mistake.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Got answer here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168143/unauthorizedaccessexception-in-storagefile-openasync) just had to add one more line.. now the downloading code is

```
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, imageUri);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var fs = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
                DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outStream);
                writer.WriteBytes(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
                await writer.StoreAsync();
                writer.DetachStream();
                await fs.FlushAsync();
                outStream.Dispose();
                fs.Dispose();
            }
```