# Do using statements and await keywords play nicely in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, using-statement

I have a situation where I am making an `async` call to a method that returns and `IDisposable` instance. For example:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

Now before `async` was on the scene, when working with an `IDisposable` instance, this call and code that used the "response" variable would be wrapped in a using statement.

My question is whether that is still the correct approach when the `async` keyword is thrown in the mix? Even though the code compiles, will the using statement still work as expected in both the examples below?

Example 1

```
using(HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com")))
{
    // Do something with the response

    return true;
}
```

Example 2

```
using(HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com")))
{
    await this.responseLogger.LogResponseAsync(response);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine.

In the first case, you're really saying:

- Asynchronously wait until we can get the response
- Use it and dispose of it immediately

In the second case, you're saying:

- Asynchronously wait until we can get the response
- Asynchronously wait until we've logged the response
- Dispose of the response

A `using` statement in an async method is "odd" in that the `Dispose` call may execute in a different thread to the one which acquired the resource (depending on synchronization context etc) but it will still happen... assuming the thing you're waiting for *ever* shows up or fail, of course. (Just like you won't end up calling `Dispose` in non-async code if your `using` statement contains a call to a method which never returns.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. While most of the async stuff is still voodoo to me, it's quite reassuring to see how often it integrates with other .net features and just works

Comment: @JonSkeet Should await even be used inside a `using(){...}` block or it's an overkill or may degrade performance in some cases? Does `using(){...}` serve the same purpose as `await`?

Comment: @nam: No, `using` and `await` serve entirely different purposes. Note that C# 8 now has asynchronous disposal as well. While it's worth being aware of the threading issue my answer highlights, that definitely doesn't mean it's *wrong* to mix `using` and `await`.