# Calling synchronous method from asynchronous method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I'm implementing `EmailServer` for ASP.NET Identity.

I don't like how `async...await` is not compatible with `using`, and so my email method is synchronous.

So how can I call it from the framework's `SendAsync` method?

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        Email email = new Email();
        return Task.FromResult<void>(email.Send(message));
    }
}
```

In the code above, `Task.FromResult()` gives me an error saying `void` can't be used as an argument type. But `email.Send()` returns void!

How to get out of this quagmire?

Comment: What exactly you don't like about `using` and `async` (like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566547/do-using-statements-and-await-keywords-play-nicely-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I found examples saying that wasn't valid code, and I saw that `SmtpClient.SendAsync()` takes a second argument that appears related to a callback. That's what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: OT: The [documentation for SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient) recommends using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) and [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have a result, then don't try to return a result. Just return a plain, completed `Task`:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        new Email().Send(message);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

If you are stuck in pre-4.6 land, then you can use `Task.FromResult<bool>(true)` instead.

All that said, I'm confused by your comment about *"`async...await` is not compatible with `using`"*. In my experience, that works fine. And it would be much better if your method were in fact asynchronous. I think you would be better served by focusing on how to do that, rather than what the best/correct syntax is for faking an `async` method.

**Addendum:**

I am still not clear on your concern about the use of `using`. However, based on your comment, it seems you would like to use `SmtpClient.SendAsync()` but are uncertain as to how to apply that in the context of `async`/`await`.

Unfortunately, even before `async`/`await`, we had lots of asynchronous methods in .NET, and those methods used the same naming as the convention for new awaitable methods. (To be clear: it's the naming that's unfortunate, not that the async methods existed :) ). However, in all cases, it is possible to adapt the old API to the new.

In some cases, it's as simple as using the `Task.FromAsync()` method. That works with anything that supports the old `Begin...`/`End...` model. But the `SmtpClient.SendAsync()` model is an event-based callback approach, which requires a slightly different approach.

NOTE: I noticed after writing the example below that the `SmtpClient` class has a `Task`-based method for asynchronous operation, [`SendMailAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx). So in reality, there's no need to adapt the older `SendAsync()` method. But it's a useful example to use, to show how one might do such adaptation when a `Task`-based alternative hasn't been provided.

Briefly, you can use `TaskCompletionSource` with the `SendCompleted` event on the `SmtpClient` object. Here's an outline of what that would look like:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // I'm not familiar with "IdentityMessage". Let's assume for the sake
        // of this example that you can somehow adapt it to the "MailMessage"
        // type required by the "SmtpClient" object. That's a whole other question.
        // Here, "IdentityToMailMessage" is some hypothetical method you write
        // to handle that. I have no idea what goes inside that. :)
        using (MailMessage mailMessage = IdentityToMailMessage(message))
        using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            // Configure "smtpClient" as needed, such as provided host information.
            // Not shown here!

            smtpClient.SendCompleted += (sender, e) => taskSource.SetResult(true);
            smtpClient.SendAsync(mailMessage, null);

            await taskSource.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

The above will start the asynchronous operation, and use the `SendCompleted` event's handler (i.e. the "callback" to which the documentation refers) to set the result for the `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` object (the result value is never really used, but there's no plain-vanilla `Task` version of `TaskCompletionSource`…you have to have *some* value).

It uses `await`, rather than returning the `taskSource.Task` object directly, because that way it can correctly handle disposing the `SmtpClient` object when the email operation has in fact completed.

Comment: I've got the latest bits. But I found a bunch of examples that avoided a `using` block in an asychronous method. I'm looking deepter into this but `SmtpClient.SendAsync()` requires a second argument, which only appears to make sense in the context of some sort of callback.

Comment: You can pass `null` for the callback data, if you don't have any need for it. See edit above for one way to adapt the `SmtpClient.SendAsync()` method to the `async`/`await` pattern

Comment: I did not notice before, but there is in fact a `Task`-compatible send method in `SmtpClient`: [`SendMailAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx). I will leave the above, as an example of how to generally adapt event-based asynchronous APIs to `Task`-based, but in fact in this particular scenario, it would be better to just use the `SendMailAsync()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments. I had also just found `SendMailAsync()` before your update. That one appears to behave as expected, and the one I'll likely use. But that _is_ a little confusing.

Comment: Well, surely the `SendAsync()` method existed long before TPL came along, never mind `async`/`await`. So I understand the presence of two different methods. If in C# a method overload could vary only by return type, they might even have kept the same name. But they couldn't do that. I'm not sure I'd have picked the name `SendMailAsync()`, as it's not really different enough from `SendAsync()` and doesn't adequately distinguish the two. But they didn't ask me. :)