# Exception while posting to web API, HTTPClient already disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm posting a bytearray from an Android App in Xamarin.Forms to an .NET Core 2.0 WebAPI. However, I'm getting an exception saying that the NetworkStream already is disposed;

Code making the request;

```
public async Task PostImageAsync(ImageDTO image)
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(image.Content);
    content.Add(byteArrayContent, image.FileTile, image.FileName);

    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = GetNewHttpClient())
        {
            SetBearerToken(httpClient);

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{_apiUrl}/api/images/upload", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Exception occurs here
        var msg = e.GetBaseException().Message;

        throw;
    }
}
```

**Code to get the HttpClient**

```
private HttpClient GetNewHttpClient()
{
     //HttpClientHandler is a global variable                
     var httpClient = new HttpClient(HttpClientHandler, false) {BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiUrl)};

    return httpClient;
}
```

**API Endpoint**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0) return BadRequest();

    return Ok();
}
```

**EDIT - SetBearerToken Method**

```
private static void SetBearerToken(HttpClient client)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", App.StoredToken);
        }
```

**The Exception:**

```
cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
```

It feels like a really obvious mistake I'm making here, but I can't get my head around it. Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Is `HttpClientHandler` used before this call?

Comment: And what is happening in SetBearerToken?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, No this is the first and only method in the API using it

Comment: @Seb, I'll update the question with that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't dispose objects inside async functions

> A `using` statement in an async method is "odd" in that the `Dispose`
>   call may execute in a different thread to the one which acquired the
>   resource (depending on synchronization context etc) but it will still
>   happen... assuming the thing you're waiting for *ever* shows up or
>   fail, of course. (Just like you won't end up calling `Dispose` in
>   non-async code if your `using` statement contains a call to a method
>   which never returns.)
>
> @jon-skeet https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566605/2228916

Answer (score 0):

Don’t dispose of the `HttpClient`:

https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Also noticed that you set `_apiUrl` as the `BaseAddress` and prefix the url in the post. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this

Comment: You have to dispose of the `HttpClient`, this is plain wrong.